# Multiple search filtering is not working in cloudant, why?

Tags: cloudant

Here i quoted my code for multiple search filtering. I could not find the mistakes in that. please give a right code to make it work well.

Employee document:

{
  "_id": "527c8d9327c6f27f17df0d2e17000530",

"_rev": "24-276a8dc913559901897fd601d2f9654f",

"proj_role": "TeamMember",

"work_total_experience": "3",

"personal": {
  "languages_known": [
   "English","Telugu"
]},

"skills": [

```
{

  "skill_set": "Webservices Framework",
  "skill_exp": 1,
  "skill_certified": "yes",
  "skill_rating": 3,
},
{
 "skill_set": "Microsoft",
  "skill_exp": 1,
  "skill_certified": "yes",
  "skill_rating": 3,
}
```

]
  "framework_competency": "Nasscom",
  "type": "employee-docs"
}

Design Document:

{
  "_id": "_design/sample",

"_rev": "86-1250f792e6e84f6f33447a00cf64d61d",

"views": {},

"language": "javascript",

"indexes": {

```
"search": {

  "index": "function(doc){\n index(\"default\", doc._id);if(doc.type=='employee-docs'){\nif (doc.proj_role){index(\"project_role\", doc.proj_role);}if(doc.work_total_experience){\nindex(\"work_experience\", doc.work_total_experience);}\nif(doc.personal.languages_known){for(c in doc.personal.languages_known){ \n index(\"languages_known\",doc.personal.languages_known[c]);}} if(doc.skills){for (var i=0;i<doc.skills.length;i++){\nindex('skill_set',doc.skills[i].skill_set);}}}}"

}
```

}
}

Run using below URL : https://ideyeah4.cloudant.com/opteamize_new/_design/sample/_search/search?q=project_role:TeamMember%20AND%20work_experience:%223%22%20AND%20languages_known:Telugu%20AND%20skill_set:Microsoft&include_docs=true

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to debug this is to query the top 100 results in your index:

```
https://ideyeah4.cloudant.com/opteamize_new/_design/sample/_search/search?q=*:*&limit=100
```

This will at least tell you whether there are any documents in your index at all.

Your current query (without URL encoding) looks like:

```
project_role:TeamMember AND work_experience:"3" AND languages_known:Telugu AND skill_set:Microsoft
```

I'd suggest that some of these search values require quotes - always true when you are searching string values. Next, you could try:

```
project_role:"TeamMember"
```

see if you get any results and refine from there.

Debugging this might also be easier if you store the values as well as index them (so you can see exactly what is indexed). To do this, add an object to each index call { "store": true }. For example,

```
index("languages_known", doc.personal.languages_known[c], { "store": true });
```

Now, when you query the index it will return a list of fields which were stored with each match.